# Airflow Task not running - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to run airflow to deploy the cloud function as a sample. But when I run it in airflow webserver, I am getting the following error.

```
[2019-12-11 03:52:07,181] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [[34m2019-12-11 03:52:07,180[0m] 
{[34mdiscovery.py:[0m867} INFO[0m - URL being requested: GET 
https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/locations/us- 
central1/functions/airflow?alt=json[0m
[2019-12-11 03:52:07,181] {taskinstance.py:1047} ERROR - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 
'NoneType' and 'int'
```

My code is as below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators import gcp_compute_operator
from airflow.contrib.sensors import gcs_sensor 
from airflow.contrib.operators import gcp_function_operator
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import airflow
import logging

SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = '@daily'
args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": datetime(2019, 12, 10),
    "retries": 3
}

GCP_CONN_ID = "bq_conn_id"
dag = DAG("staging_deployment", default_args=args, 
schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL)

t4 = gcp_function_operator.GcfFunctionDeployOperator(
task_id="gcf_deploy2_task",
project_id="projectid",
location="us-central1",
body={
    "name":"projects/projectid/locations/us-central1/functions/airflow",
    "entryPoint":"airflow",
    "runtime":"python37",
    "sourceArchiveUrl":"gcs bucket details",
    "httpsTrigger":{}
},
validate_body=True,
dag=dag,
gcp_conn_id=GCP_CONN_ID
)
t4
```

please advice

Comment: there must be some variable type issues, check the variable and its type

Comment: I dont think there are any variables declared or used. For clear question, I have added the complete code. The goal is I am running this code in VM instance of Google cloud platform and deploying the cloud function as per the code

Comment: Which Airflow version is this?

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint @Sergiy Upgrading to airflow version did a trick. may be related to this https://github.com/CTFd/CTFd/issues/567

Comment: @python_interest Glad that you was able to solve the problem. It may help others with the same problem if you mention which Airflow version you used and to which one you upgraded.

Comment: Thank you @Sergiy I have updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message `[2019-12-11 03:52:07,181] {taskinstance.py:1047} ERROR - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'` you have to find the file `taskinstance.py`, then search for the line 1047 and see which of the operands becomes `None`.

Your code is too short to find the line 1047, you have to paste the longer one or do it yourself.

Comment: taskinstance.py is from airflow itself. The code is running airflow behind the scenes

Comment: @python_interest Still, this is where I would start debugging the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the hint @Sergiy Upgrading to airflow version did a trick. may be related to this github.com/CTFd/CTFd/issues/567 . I was using Airflow 1.10.4 before and upgraded to 1.10.6 .